# Setting View visibility to Invisible and getting the dimensions

Tags: android

I have an ImageView with its **visibility** set as **GONE**. I am trying to set a Bitmap Resource onto it and make it appear.

I realize the dimensions of the ImageView (which I need to subsample my bitmap appropriately) is zero when it's visibility is still **GONE**, so I set this line of code just before my BitmapAsyncTask runs.

```
ImageView postImageView= (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.post_image);
// Set it as visible to take up necessary space for bitmap computation
postImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

The dimensions still return zero and upon further testing, the ImageView takes some time before it's visibility is set to INVISIBLE again. My fix for now is a while loop inside the AsyncTask to wait until the dimensions are available, but I would like to find out whether there is a better way to do this?

My current code for the AsyncTask:

```
 @Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    Log.i(TAG,"BitmapWorkerTask initialized.");
    while(mImageView.getWidth() ==0){
        // Wait for the ImageView to be ready
        Log.i(TAG,"asd");
    }
    int reqWidth = mImageView.getWidth()==0?1920:mImageView.getWidth();
    int reqHeight = mImageView.getHeight()==0?1080:mImageView.getHeight();
    Log.i(TAG, "Dimensions (required): "+reqWidth+" X "+ reqHeight);
    //Decode and scale image
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, options);
    Log.i(TAG, "Dimensions (source): "+options.outWidth+" X "+ options.outHeight);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,reqWidth, reqHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath,options);
    Log.i(TAG,"Dimensions (Bitmap): "+ imageBitmap.getWidth()+" X "+ imageBitmap.getHeight());

    return imageBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a layout listener, to wait for the layout to be measured:

```
final ImageView postImageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.post_image);

postImageView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View view, int i, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7, int i8) {
        postImageView.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
        Log.e(TAG, "W:" + postImageView.getWidth() + " H:"+postImageView.getHeight());
    }
});

postImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks! I put my AsyncTask inside OnLayoutChange and it works perfectly :)